# How to access a layout within a listView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in an Activity and in that ListView I have another Layout which gives the list its content. Here is the code

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(),listvalue,
                 R.layout.singlepost,v,s);                                            
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

singlepost is the layout I load into the listView but this singlepost has a couple of buttons I want to access but i cannot access thebuttons because it is not loaded with the activity containing the ListView so when i try to access the button like this

```
ImageButton star = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.star);
```

It Tells me the View you are trying to access is not within this activity. I know it is impossible to use two `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` except you use Fragments. so how do I access the button in the singlepost layout.

Note: When I mean Access, I mean to click and have the button do something and I have done all the necessaries declarations and instantiations all i need is a way to access that button. Thanks. Hope My question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty you will have to make your own adapter that extends some Adapter (`SimpleAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter`, ...). And in the `getView()` method set any neccessary listeners:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);    
        }

        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Perform action on click
               }
            });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Or an example with `SimpleAdapter`. Note that I haven't tried it, but it should theoretically work I believe.

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List  list, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, list, resource, from, to);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Button button = (Button) convertView .findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: so do I take out my initial SimpleApadter declaration and replace with this new class?

Comment: yes, but if you extend `ArrayAdapter` as in this example, you will have to set all the `TextView`s as well.

Comment: @daviestobialex or see edit for an example with `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: @daviestobialex yeah sorry that did suppose to say convertView.findViewById(); Which example gives you NPE?